# How to Change a div width when size of browser window change with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to Change a div width when size of browser window change with javascript (no jQuery)?
I want to perform this job dynamically when user resize his browser.
Please help, Immediately ...
any suggestion for this job with css?

Comment: why not only with css?

Comment: Have you read up on the resize event? What have you tried so far? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/resize

Comment: You should use CSS for as simple a task as this because under heavy load, CSS performs much better jQuery.

Comment: Why would you do this via `Javascript`? use `CSS`. You can do something like `div { width: 80%; }` that will resize depending of the size of the window, keeping the `div` at `80%` of the window. If not that you can look into [**Media Queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 2):

Use percentage. for example `width="50%"` This will change the width when browser size change.

Comment: this code doesn't work for me because the parent of div element has fixed width and shoulde has a fixed width.

Answer (score 2):

You can either set this with CSS or Javscript

CSS would be easily done using %'s ie

```
div {
    width: 95%;
}
```

JS would be easily done using

```
var element = document.getElementById("x");
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    element.style.width = window.style.width;
});
```

Comment: What exactly doesnt work? jsfiddle would be great to help you out

Answer (score 0):

This code should work in all browsers. But you really should use CSS instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8" />
    <title>untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv" style=" height: 200px; margin:10px auto; background: green;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myElement = document.getElementById('myDiv');
function detectWidth(){
    var myWidth = 0;
    if(typeof (window.innerWidth)== 'number'){
        myWidth = window.innerWidth; 
    }
    else {
        myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;  //IE7
    }
    myElement.style.width=myWidth-300+'px';
}
window.onload=function(){
    detectWidth();  
};
window.onresize = function (){
    detectWidth();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```